# Named non-resourceful routes create url methods that are accessible ActiveRecord instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4.2

Here's part of my `config/routes.rb`

```
require 'resque/server'

Rails.application.routes.draw do

  get 'tools/index',  as: :tools

  get 'search/index', as: :search

  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
  authenticate :admin_user do
    mount Resque::Server.new, at: '/admin/jobs'
  end

  # ...
end
```

I just learned that the URL methods generated by named non-resourceful routes, in this case `tools_path`, `tools_url`, `feed_path` and `feed_url` get injected / accessible to all ActiveRecord object. Like the following in Rails console:

```
> user = User.first
...
> user.feed_path
=> "/feed"
> user.feed_url
=> "http://my-app.dev/feed"
> user.search_path
=> "/search/index"
> user.search_url
=> "http://my-app.dev/search/index"
```

I'm using Rails 4.2.1 on Ruby 2.0.0p598. I don't know if this worth mentioning, initially the app is in Rails 4.1.x. I can't reproduce it on a fresh Rails 4.2.1 app. So definitely not a Rails bug. How to debug this?

Comment: What is not working in Rails 4.2.1?

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: The problem is `user` object should not have those methods.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out the ActiveRecord models I tried in Rails console use a concern that includes `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers`. Duh?!